# Shap Summary plot does not show the distribution and concentration of data points properly

Tags: conv-neural-network, classification, image-classification, shap

I have trained a classifier to categorize images into 4 classes using VGG16 network+ with a few FCN layers, and it works very well.

I am now trying to plot the SHap summary plot figures to reveal the impact of different deep features on the output. For this purpose, I used the second to the last layer of the network (the layer before the classifier), including 32 features.

Here is how I plot the Shap figure:

```
model_1 = load_model(model_file) # Loading the model


# On Training set

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,  # this is the target directory
        target_size=target_size,  # all images will be resized to the target size
        color_mode='rgb',
        batch_size=1,
        shuffle=False,
        class_mode='categorical',
        interpolation='nearest',
        seed=42) 

true_classes = train_generator.classes # label numbers for all samples

train_generator.reset() # it resets the train generator to start loading data from zero. 

model_1.summary()

model_1_droput=keras.Model(inputs=model_1.input, outputs=model_1.get_layer('dense_1').output) # The input is the model's original input, and the output is the dense layer containing 32 features.


pred_dropout=model_1_droput.predict(train_generator) # generating output 32 features on for all data


classifier=keras.Model(inputs=model_1.get_layer('dense_1').output, outputs=model_1.output) # using this classifier for the shap analysis
classifier.summary()



# load JS visualization code to notebook
shap.initjs()


columns = [f'Deep feature {i}' for i in range(32)] # naming the deep features from 0-31


label_dict={0:"Class 0", 1:"Class 1", 2:"Class 2", 3:"Class 3"}


explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(classifier, pred_dropout)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(pred_dropout, check_additivity=False)



## Shap Summary plot

fig = plt.figure()
class_type_index=0 # Choosing one of the class types

shap.summary_plot(shap_values[class_type_index], features=pred_dropout[indexes], feature_names=columns, alpha=0.2) # plotting the shap summary plot.
```

Here is the output I get:

[image]

There are two issues with this plot:

1. The density of data points is not clear, although I used alpha=0.2. I do not know which area has a higher concentration of data points. I need to show it somehow.
2. The distribution of data points are somewhat peculiar. I do not expect the distribution to show stepwise change and stay the same for various ranges. The following figure, that I got from [here](https://www.aidancooper.co.uk/a-non-technical-guide-to-interpreting-shap-analyses/), makes a lot of sense with various densities and different distributions for each feature horizontally.

[image]

Mine has got a more rectangular, step-wise distribution. You can draw literally straight lines for each deep feature shown, which does not make much sense. Additionally, I do not know which area has a higher density of data points. Something is not right here, but I do not know where.

Your help is very much appreciated.